# Appcelerator iOS. is it possible to open a specific screen on Click of Push Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have Apple Push Notification in my app.

I need to open a specific page when the user clicks to a notification.

I have the following code which I think should fire callback method even when the app is not running.

```
Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications({
            success : deviceTokenSuccess,
            error : deviceTokenError,
            callback : receivePush
        });
```

When the app is not running user receives notification but receivePush method is not firing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific process which defines how push notifications (PN) works on iOS.

1. If app is in foreground, then no notification will be shown.
2. If app is in background, then you can see notifications on lock screen or in notification center.

**Now in 2nd case, your callback event will be fired up only & only when user taps on the notification itself.**

**It will never be fired up if you don't tap on notification or you directly open up the app from app icon.**

Coming to your primary query to open up a specific section in the app is totally depend on you that how you define your app structure or how you handle the data inside your code.

iOS will only provide you the calling of the PN callback method and also note that PN callback should be registered in every app session, i.e., every time you runs the app, PN callback should be registered in order to call this method upon tapping on PN.

Comment: Thanks! Working now!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with local notifications? I tried to monitor the `notification` and `localnotification` events but they are never called when tapped on local notification.